# rename all files in folder to numbered list 1.jpg 2.jpg

Tags: linux, command-line

I have a folder full of images with several different random file names to help organize this mess I would like to, in one command rename all of them to a sequential order so if I have 100 files it starts off naming the first file `file-1.jpg` `file-2.jpg` etc. Is this possible in one command?

Comment: If I knew how to write a shell script to accomplish this I probably would have done that haha

Comment: Well sounds like a good time to learn then!

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, bring it to us to help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you.  Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there.  Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by writing a bash script

```
#!/bin/sh
num=1
for file in *.jpg; do
       mv "$file" "$(printf "%u" $num).jpg"
       let num=$num+1
done
```

Comment: sh does not have `let`. it just cost me 2 hours of work. it must be `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: the same for me. I needed to put #!/bin/bash

Comment: would be safe and change mv to cp, then delete files we don't need

Answer (score 63):

The most concise command line to do this I can think of is

```
ls | cat -n | while read n f; do mv "$f" "file-$n.jpg"; done
```

`ls` lists the files in the current directory and `cat -n` adds line numbers.  The `while` loop reads the resulting numbered list of files line by line, stores the line number in the variable `n` and the filename in the variable `f` and performs the rename.

Comment: Thank You! This should be marked as the answer

Comment: Be careful, if there is a file with "file-$n.jpg" name it will be overwritten! As a consequence, files could be lost.

Comment: what is the difference between using "|" and ";" ? Also how is n and f filled? I don't understand the concept here.

Comment: @Tak You are asking about the fundamentals of shell scripting.  I guess I won't be able to teach you a complex programming language in a single SO comment :) so I'd ask you to read some shell scripting tutorial first.

Comment: @SvenMarnach can you send me a link to start with? :)

Comment: @Tak I don't happen to know a good one, and it depends on your goals and your prior knowledges anyway.  Just google for it and pick one.  (I learned most of it from the `bash` and `dash` man pages, which are rather special, so I don't recommend to immitate this way of learning POSIX shell.)