# Change filenames in a specific folder through bash

Tags: linux, bash, filenames

I have a folder FOLDER1 with different files in it.

I have several files in the folder with an extension .png

I would like to change the filename of all the files with extension .png with a bash script. I tried to write one but I still didn't arrive to have what I want.

```
#!/bin/bash
# make sure you always put $f in double quotes to avoid any nasty surprises i.e. "$f"
i=0
for f in *.png
do
  echo "${i}Processing $f file..."
  i+=1;
  echo ${i}
  # rm "$f"
done
```

At the end of the script I would like to have all the files named like:

c-1.png

c-2.png

c-3.png

...

...

...

Could you help me?
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18686832/rename-all-files-in-folder-to-numbered-list-1-jpg-2-jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I found my solution .

This code is working perfectly.

```
#!/bin/bash
# make sure you always put $f in double quotes to avoid any nasty surprises i.e. "$f"
i=0
for f in *.png
do
  echo "$i Processing $f file..."
  i=$((i+1))
  mv $f "c-"$i.png
  #echo ${i}
done
```

Answer (score 1):

First note that:

```
i+=1
```

is string addition. What you're doing is 0,01,011,0111.... You need:

```
((++i))
```

Next you need to split your file name, one way if "." appears only once:

```
base=$(echo $f | cut -d. -f1)
```

and finally move:

```
mv $f ${base}-${i}.png
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
for f in *.png
do
  echo "${i}Processing $f file..."
  i=$((i + 1))
  newname="c-${i}.png"
  mv "$f" $newname
done
```

Comment: Yes , I arrived to the same conclusion. Thanks all for the replies.